# Jenkins pipline with conditions

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Hi I am trying to make a jenkins pipeline with certain conditions. The build is triggered either from the backend or frontend repository. Depending on the $git_project variable, I need to run either one stage or another. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a pipeline like the one below. Here you can use `when{}` directive to conditionally execute a stage. You can read more [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when).

```
def git_project = "abcd"

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Stage 01') {
            when { expression { git_project == "abcd"}
                
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Stage 1'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Stage 02') {
            when { expression { git_project == "cdef"}
                
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Stage 2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```